# Can I calculate Geometric Angle numeric value

Tags: excel-formula

I want to find the Geometrical angle target based on the below inputs :

If 45 Degree angle has the numeric value of 762

Then what is the value of 63.75 and 26.25 degree values? How to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just looking for a conversion factor?  i.e. Converting Angles to Radians?  45 degrees = 0.785398 Radians.  There is a `RADIANS` function in Excel.. =RADIAN(45) =  RADIANS(63.75) etc.

Comment: @goodjuju Thanks. Yes. I'm aware of that conversion factor. But I need  @ 45 degree angle the number is 762, then how much the value of 762 @ 63.75 degree angle. That's what I need? Can I multiply with 1.112647 (radians of 63.75) to get the answer. Is it correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

We can find what you need based on the information that you have:

45 degrees (your base point of reference) is equivalent to 762 'units'

We can find the `ratio` between 45 and 762 using a formula (`GCD` is `Greatest Common Divider`):

Formula in C2 = (ratio)

```
=A2/GCD(A2,B2) & ":" & B2/GCD(A2,B2)<br>
```

E2= (ratio 1)

```
=A2/GCD(A2,B2)
```

F2= (ratio 2)

```
=B2/GCD(A2,B2)
```

[image]

Looking at the above image, we can see that for every 15 degrees there are 254 'other units'.

We can now use the ratio values for our calculations:

We can divide any value in degrees by 15 (ratio 1) and multiply the result by 254 (ratio 2) to get our answer:

[image]

Formula in B5 (copied down) =

```
=SUM(A5/$D$2)*$E$2
```

Note that the references to the ratio's (D2 & E2) are absolute references (with $) and will not change as the formula is copied.

Comment: You are welcome.  If my answer resolved your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Accepting an answer is beneficial as it rewards posters for correctly answering your question and informs others that your issue is resolved.